# Android Merge libs gradle

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1002
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }



}
dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    api 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    api 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.0.0'
    api 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    api 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    api 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    api 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1'
    api 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    api "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha03"
    api 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'



}
```

On build app, I get next error:

```
 Task :mobile:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list:
  Error while merging dex archives: 
  Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
```

I found the error. Error in library incompatibility `"androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha03"` and `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'`.

How can I fix the error without deleting `androidx.fragment` dependency?

UPD. Solution:

```
api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
api "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0"
```

Comment: Try to use `"androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0"` instead of  `"androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha03"`. And also you can try to reduce `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'` to `1.0.0`.

Comment: @Timur Gaysin: Congrats for the solution! You can make the solution as an answer then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Replace:

```
api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
api "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha03"
```

to:

```
api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
api "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0"
```

Hopefully, the AndroidX library will become more stable ...